# javascript indexes from codewars

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

I am working on the following codewars problem. The question looks like this:

> Instructions
>
> Write a function capitals that takes a single string (word) as
> argument. The functions must return an ordered list containing the
> indexes of all capital letters in the string.
>
> Example
>
> Test.assertSimilar( capitals('CodEWaRs'), [0,3,4,6] );

And my solution is:

```
function capitals(word){
  var ara = []
  for(var i = 0; i < word.length; i++){
    if(word[i] == word[i].toUpperCase()){
      ara.push(word.indexOf(word[i]))
    }
  }
 return ara
}
```

The code works fine whenever I pass a string to it. The only problem I have is I am getting the same index for a repeated spelling. for instance, `capitals("HeLLo")` returns `[0, 2, 2]` instead of `[0, 3, 4]`.
Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Shouldn't `capitals("Hello")` return `[0]` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're doing `word.indexOf(word[i])` when you already have the index in `i`.

Comment: You are right. I forgot to make both 'l' capital. I'm Gonna edit it. Thanks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/RT7ps/

Comment: adeneo jsfiddle.net/RT7ps is cool.

Answer (score 1):

`word.indexOf(word[i])` returns the *first* index, you should simply push `i` onto the array.

Answer (score 1):

Say this

```
ara.push(i)
```

instead of

```
ara.push(word.indexOf(word[i]))
```

When you will say `word.indexOf(word[i]))` it will return the very first `index` where it get the `word[i]`. So for both `L` it's giving 2.

Comment: alright, that fixed the problem. Thank you Mritunjay

Answer (score 0):

You may find the solutions above satisfactory but I thought I would provide a more functional approach in ES2015.

```
const capitals = word => word.split('') // split word into an array

  .map((letter, idx) => letter === letter.toUpperCase() ? idx : false)
  // return a new array that gives the index of the capital letter

  .filter(num => Number.isInteger(num));
  // filter through each item in the new array and return 
  // a newer array of just the index values
```